# Running Cron Job w/ Sudo permissions

Tags: trash, sudo, cron

Strictly for learning purposes (possibly maintenance as well) I am trying to have a Cron job empty my trash once a day.

I have opened terminal and entered the command `crontab -e` to access the VI editor to add the command. I've entered Insert mode and added `* * * * * sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash/*`, hit the escape key to exit and quit VI with `:wq!`

This particular script I have running every minute just to see if it works and it is not. I thought it might be an issue with cron not having root access, so I added the same line to the `sudo crontab -e` file and it doesn't seem to be saving.

Any ideas what could be wrong with this cron job?

Comment: Why are you trying to delete the files from your user's `.Trash` with `sudo` in the first place? Is your sudoers configuration set to NOPASSWD?

Comment: @techraf Does running anything is Cron automatically grant sudo rights? if not, how can I run sudo rights within a Cron job?

Comment: I asked you two questions, please answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think you need to use sudo.  You don't.  You're not trying to empty root's Trash folder. You have permission to delete files in your own `~/.Trash` folder, so you don't need to become root (which is what sudo does) to do the `rm`.

You can simply use:

```
* * * * * rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
```

Note, I'd also advise against using `~` in a dangerous command like this (any time you're calling `rm -rf` it's potentially dangerous). Put the full path to the `.Trash` folder so it's very explicit what will happen when the line is executed. Something like `/Users/yourusername/.Trash/`. So:

```
* * * * * rm -rf /Users/yourusername/.Trash/*
```

Where you replace `yourusername` with your actual user name on the host.

Comment: Thank you for the well explained answer! That makes sense and it worked!

Comment: re ~ ut is not a recommendation not to use it. It just does not work in cron

Answer (score 3):

If you want to specify the the root user's crontab, you have to use the `-u` option.

`sudo crontab -e -u root`

That said, there's a safer way to clean out your trash than just removing the whole directory.  Personally, I like to remove files that are older than a certain number of days.  This way, if I inadvertently delete something today, I have a "buffer" of time in which to recover from.

The following command will delete all files that are **older** than 15 days.

`find ~/.Trash/ -type f -mtime +15 -exec rm {} \;`

Now...that said...

`cron` has been deprecated for `launchd`.  I would take some time and [learn how to create `.plist` XML files for `lauchd`](http://www.launchd.info/) and use that service instead of `cron`

Comment: This was super helpful as well!